# Add a variable to Javascript's replace function

Tags: javascript

I need to add to *Javascript* replace function a variable.

This example works fine:

```
form = form.replace(/1/g, form_count);
```

But I need to replace the number with a variable "s" :

```
var s = 1;
form = form.replace('/'+s+'/g', form_count);
```

This code is not working, how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but try `var s = "1";`

Comment: `.replace` and regular expressions are built into JavaScript, they have nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
form = form.replace(new RegExp(s, 'g'), form_count);
```

You will have to escape Regex special chars in s though.